# component interval of open set

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, connectedness

Let $S$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$. An open interval $I \subseteq S$ is called a component interval if there doesn't exists an open interval $J\neq I$ such that $I \subseteq J \subseteq S$.

> Show that Every point $a$ of a non-empty open set $S$ belongs to exactly one component interval of $S$.

---

**My approach:**

Let's choose an arbitrary $a\in S$. As $S$ is open there exists a set $U_{\epsilon}(a)\subseteq S$ where $U_{\epsilon}(a):=\{x\in \mathbb{R}\mid |x-a|<\epsilon\}$. Either $U_{\epsilon}(a)$ is a component interval or it isn't. If it isn't then there must be a  $J\subseteq S$ such that $U_{\epsilon}(a)\subset J$. Hence, $a$ lies in at least one component interval.

Let be $I\neq \emptyset$ an arbitrary index set which contains more than one element and $J_i$ with $i\in I$ a component interval of $S$. We assume that $a\in\bigcap\limits_{i\in I}J_i$ and define the set $M:=\bigcup\limits_{i\in I}J_i$ which is open. Next, we show by contradiction that $M$ must be connected.

If we assumed that we can find two open sets $Q_1$ und $Q_2$ (both $\subseteq \mathbb{R}$) where $M\subseteq (Q_1\cup Q_2)$, $ Q_1\cap Q_2=\emptyset$, $M\cap Q_1\neq \emptyset$ and $M\cap Q_2\neq\emptyset$. Then there must be an element $r\in I$ such that $J_r\subseteq Q_2$ und $M\setminus J_r\subseteq Q_1$.

However, $a\in\bigcap\limits_{i\in I}J_i$ so we have $a\in (Q_1\cap Q_2)$ or in other words $(Q_1\cap Q_2)\neq \emptyset$. This shows that $M$ is a connectd set in $\mathbb{R}$ and therefore an open interval. As $M$ contains all $J_i$ those $J_i$ cannot be component intervals which is a contradiction (Note that this also includes the case $M=S$). Hence, the index set can only contain one element which shows that $a$ belongs to exactly one component interval.

---

I know that there already exist some proofs on MSE which prove this theorem. However, as my approach is different I would like to know if it is correct. My tutor thinks that it is wrong but he had no time to tell me why and if it is completely wrong or if this approach can be repaired.

Any feedback is welcome :)

Comment: For the first part, why should $J$ be a component interval? (Which seems to be what you are implying.)

Comment: I think what you are doing in the second part is ok; I am having a hard time following it, though... But I think you are trying to say the following: if two component intervals have a common element, they must be identical; for otherwise their union would contradict the definition of component interval.

Comment: @DavidMitra, ahh ok I see - this is a mistake.  So I think that in the first part I can't avoid it to somehow construct a component interval. Regarding the second part, I am saying that if a number of component intervals have a common element then you can take the union and the union is an intervall that contains all those component intervals. So we have a bigger open interval that contains the component intervals which contradicts the definition of a component interval.

Comment: So the second part is ok (for your presented argument, you need to assume the $J_i$ are not all the same at the start (and there you need only consider 2 sets)).

Comment: @DavidMitra, we have the following definition of a connected set (which is an interval in $\mathbb{R}$): 

Let be $(X,\Vert \cdot\Vert)$ a normed space. $M$ is connected if there doesn't exist two open sets $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ such that $M\subseteq(Q_1\cup Q_2)$, $Q_1 \cap Q_2=\emptyset$, $M\cap Q_1\neq \emptyset$ and $M\cap Q_2\neq \emptyset$.

I hope this helps.

Comment: @DavidMitra, thanks for your tips. So it turns out that my approach when corrected and improved "converges" to the one that already lives here on MSE.

Comment: I'm aware of the definition of a connected set. I was just remarking that you would not obtain a contradiction if all the $J_i$ were identical.